# Drawing balls from urns as an example of conditional independence

Tags: probability

There are $m+1$ urns with $m$ balls in each. In the $i$th urn there are $i-1$ red balls and the rest of them are blue. First we choose an urn with uniform probability and then we repeat the process of drawing a ball and putting it back for this chosen urn $n$ times. What is the probability that all $n$ balls are red?

**My attempt**

Let $B_k$ be the event that the $k$th ball is red and $A_i$ be the event that we choose the $i$th urn. We want to find $P(B_1\cap\cdots\cap B_n)$. Now this is the part I'm not sure about: $P(B_1\cap\cdots\cap B_n)=\sum^{m+1}_{i=1}P(B_1\cap\cdots\cap B_n|A_i)P(A_i)$ and since $B_k$ are conditionally independent with respect to $A_i$ we have $P(B_1\cap\cdots\cap B_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}(\frac{i-1}{m})^n\frac{1}{m+1}$. Is there are more compact form for this sum? Is my result even correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is correct, it's

$$\frac{1}{m^n(m+1)} \sum_{i=1}^{m} i^n$$

It is possible to write that sums with [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) which for generic values of $n$ is a bit "heavy", for $n=1,2,3$ these formulas are knows so we should use it:

- n=1  $\frac{1}{m(m+1)} \sum_{i=1}^{m} i=\frac{m(m+1)}{2m(m+1)}=\frac{1}{2}$
- n=2  $\frac{1}{m^2(m+1)} \sum_{i=1}^{m} i^2=\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6m^2(m+1)}=\frac{2m+1}{6m}=\frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{6m}$
- n=3 $\frac{1}{m^3(m+1)} \sum_{i=1}^{m} i^3=\frac{(m(m+1))^2}{4m^3(m+1)}=\frac{m+1}{4m}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4m}$

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you one more question?

Comment: For sure, I hope I can help

Comment: The second part of this question is: what is the probability that the $n+1$th ball will be red given that all $n$ balls were red? I think this is just basic conditional probability: $P(B_{n+1}|\bigcap^{n}B_k)=\frac{P(\bigcap^{n+1}B_k)}{P(\bigcap^{n}B_k)}=1/m$. So as $m\to\infty$ the probability tends to $0$, which is a little surprising to me, is that correct?

Comment: The first part is correct, is just conditional probability. But you have $P(\bigcap^{n+1}B_k)= \left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} i^{n+1} \right)/(m^{n+1}(m+1))$ and  $P(\bigcap^{n}B_k)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} i^n \right)/(m^n(m+1))$: you can't cancel out the sums because addenda are different.

In particular $P(B_n+1|\bigcap^n B_k)=\frac{1}{m} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m} i^{n+1}}{\sum_{i=1}^{m} i^n}$